# Nested scrolling areas: after scrolling to the bottom of the inner scroll area, the outer scroll area doesn't engage until the mouse is moved

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a page which includes a header, side-by-side list view and map view, and a footer.

The footer is meant to be below the fold, and only visible when a user scrolls to the bottom of the list view and continues scrolling down.

For aesthetic reasons, the outermost scrollbar is hidden, and only the scrollbar on the list view is visible.

The overall layout is essentially the same as the snippet I've included below.

The issue I am having is that once I have scrolled to the bottom of the list view, if I do not move the mouse at all and continue to scroll, nothing happens. If I move the mouse a few pixels in any direction and continue to scroll, then the footer will correctly scroll into view.

How can I make it so that the outer scroll view seamlessly takes over once the user reaches the bottom of the list view, to scroll the footer into view without requiring the user to first move the mouse before continuing to scroll?

Note that the only purpose of the js in the snippet is to simulate the fact that the map view zooms instead of scrolling on mousewheel events (as such, the footer does not scroll into view when scrolling the mouse wheel over the map view, which is the expected behaviour).

```js
let zoom = 64;

const handleMapScrollWheel = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const delta = e.wheelDelta ? e.wheelDelta / 30 : e.deltaY * 4 / 51
  zoom = Math.max(4, Math.min(256, zoom + delta));
document.getElementById('content').style.fontSize = `${zoom}px`;
}

document.getElementById('content').addEventListener("wheel", handleMapScrollWheel);
```

```css
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.center {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.fit-screen {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.scroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.hide-scroll {
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.hide-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background: transparent;
  width: 0;
}

.hide-scroll::-moz-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

header {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.item {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: limegreen;
  padding: 32px;
  font-size: 24px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: purple;
  font-size: 64px;
}

footer {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="column fit-screen scroll hide-scroll">
  <div class="column fit-screen">
    <header class="row center">
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </header>
    <main class="row">
      <div class="scroll">
        <ul class="column list">
          <li class="item">Item 1</li>
          <li class="item">Item 2</li>
          <li class="item">Item 3</li>
          <li class="item">Item 4</li>
          <li class="item">Item 5</li>
          <li class="item">Item 6</li>
          <li class="item">Item 7</li>
          <li class="item">Item 8</li>
          <li class="item">Item 9</li>
          <li class="item">Item 10</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="content center" id="content">
        Map View
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
  <footer class="row center">
    <h3>Footer</h3>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: The behavior doesn’t appear to change if I remove both the `hide-scroll` class and the JavaScript. And it kinda makes sense to me, I usually would not want the whole viewport content to move, when I reached the end of an in-page scrollable element.

Comment: @CBroe as I mentioned, the purpose of the javascript is just to simulate the map view. This is important because in the real implementation, a user cannot simply scroll down while the mouse is over that area to scroll the page down, as doing so will instead zoom out the map view. The hide-scroll class is partially for aesthetic purposes and partially to ensure that the page can't be scrolled down until the user reaches the bottom of the list